# Multiprocessing with python3 only runs once

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x, queue, multiprocessing

I have a problem running multiple processes in python3 .

My program does the following:
    1. Takes entries from an sqllite database and passes them to an input_queue
    2. Create multiple processes that take items off the input_queue, run it through a function and output the result to the output queue.
    3. Create a thread that takes items off the output_queue and prints them (This thread is obviously started before the first 2 steps)

My problem is that currently the 'function' in step 2 is only run as many times as the number of processes set, so for example if you set the number of processes to 8, it only runs 8 times then stops. I assumed it would keep running until it took all items off the input_queue.

Do I need to rewrite the function that takes the entries out of the database (step 1) into another process and then pass its output queue as an input queue for step 2?

Edit:
Here is an example of the code, I used a list of numbers as a substitute for the database entries as it still performs the same way. I have 300 items on the list and I would like it to process all 300 items, but at the moment it just processes 10 (the number of processes I have assigned)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue
import multiprocessing
from threading import Thread


## This is the class that would be passed to the multi_processing function
class Processor:
    def __init__(self,out_queue):
        self.out_queue = out_queue
    def __call__(self,in_queue):
        data_entry = in_queue.get()
        result = data_entry*2
        self.out_queue.put(result)



#Performs the multiprocessing
def perform_distributed_processing(dbList,threads,processor_factory,output_queue):
    input_queue = Queue()


    # Create the Data processors.
    for i in range(threads):
        processor  = processor_factory(output_queue)
        data_proc = Process(target = processor,
                            args   = (input_queue,))

        data_proc.start()

    # Push entries to the queue.

    for entry in dbList:
        input_queue.put(entry)


    # Push stop markers to the queue, one for each thread.

    for i in range(threads):
        input_queue.put(None)

    data_proc.join()
    output_queue.put(None)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    output_results   = Queue()

    def output_results_reader(queue):
        while True:
            item = queue.get()
            if item is None:
                break
            print(item)


    # Establish results collecting thread.
    results_process = Thread(target = output_results_reader,args   = (output_results,))
    results_process.start()

    # Use this as a substitute for the database in the example
    dbList = [i for i in range(300)]

    # Perform multi processing
    perform_distributed_processing(dbList,10,Processor,output_results)

    # Wait for it all to finish.
    results_process.join()
```

Comment: You will need to show us some code if you want us to debug it. Ideally give us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that's stripped down to just enough to demonstrate what you're trying to do and what goes wrong.

Comment: But most likely, the code you've gotten wrong didn't need to be written anyway, and a `multiprocessing.Pool` or `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` would do everything you need automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I added the code to the question. I am not sure if Pool would work with what I have. The line I think needs editing is the one that loops through content_table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A collection of processes that service an input queue and write to an output queue is pretty much the definition of a process pool.

If you want to know how to build one from scratch, the best way to learn is to look at the [source code for `multiprocessing.Pool`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py), which is pretty simply Python, and very nicely written. But, as you might expect, you can just *use* `multiprocessing.Pool` instead of re-implementing it. The examples in the docs are very nice.

But really, you could make this even simpler by using an [executor](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/concurrent.futures.html#executor-objects) instead of a pool. It's hard to explain the difference (again, read the docs for both modules), but basically, a [future](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/concurrent.futures.html#future-objects) is a "smart" result object, which means instead of a pool with a variety of different ways to run jobs and get results, you just need a dumb thing that doesn't know how to do anything but return futures. (Of course in the most trivial cases, the code looks almost identical either way…)

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def Processor(data_entry):
    return data_entry*2

def perform_distributed_processing(dbList, threads, processor_factory):
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(processes=threads) as executor:
        yield from executor.map(processor_factory, dbList)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Use this as a substitute for the database in the example
    dbList = [i for i in range(300)]
    for result in perform_distributed_processing(dbList, 8, Processor):
        print(result)
```

Or, if you want to handle them as they come instead of in order:

```
def perform_distributed_processing(dbList, threads, processor_factory):
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(processes=threads) as executor:
        fs = (executor.submit(processor_factory, db) for db in dbList)
        yield from map(Future.result, as_completed(fs))
```

Notice that I also replaced your in-process queue and thread, because it wasn't doing anything but providing a way to interleave "wait for the next result" and "process the most recent result", and `yield` (or `yield from`, in this case) does that without all the complexity, overhead, and potential for getting things wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't see the last reply as I forgot to refresh so was experimenting with the Pool class. This example has helped a lot and saved me a few hours this evening. Thank you !

Comment: @Lezan: Just keep in mind that there are some cases that a pool makes easier than an executor (`pool.imap` is simpler than three lines of code dealing with futures, and the chunking/batching that `pool.map` does automatically can give huge performance gains for very little work, and so on), so it's worth playing with both and understanding the differences.

Comment: For the databases executor.map seemed to work better, so I will be using that. I wasn't even aware of Pools until this morning, so this has been quite a learning experience

Comment: @Lezan: Well, you made a pretty impressive first attempt at building a pool from scratch without even knowing anything about what you were trying to build. (And you probably learned a lot in doing it, so even if you wasted some time, it wasn't really wasted in the long run.)

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to rewrite the whole multiprocessing library again. I think you can use any of `multiprocessing.Pool` methods depending on your needs - if this is a batch job you can even use the synchronous `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` - only instead of pushing to input queue, you need to write a generator that yields input to the threads.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking into Pool now. But my problem is that I am adding things to a queue for another Process to use as input (edited code above) would it still work if I am using Pool?

Comment: @Lezan: It's not the other `Process` that needs to use the queue as input, it's the _task_ that needs it. So just pass it as an argument to each function you `apply` (or build a closure over it to wrap the function you pass to `map`, of whatever).

Comment: @Lezan: Of course if everyone shares a queue, you can push it to all of the processes in the `initializer`, but that's just an optimization.

Comment: @abarnert So how would that work for the example code where you are passing items of a list to the queue. Sorry if the questions are basic I am still new to this

Comment: @Lezan: In your example code, you don't even need an explicit queue at all, because it's really just a queue of jobs. Just get rid of `in_queue`, and `pool.apply_async` your function with each new argument instead of `in_queue.put`-ting it, or just `pool.map` over the arguments. Have you read through the `multiprocessing` docs? Because the examples there are very clear and well-explained, and if I (or Antti Haapala) try to write you new examples, they're probably not going to be as good…